# Unable to remove exact name from the recyclerview when child is removed in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database, fastadapter

I have a `RecyclerView` in an activity and when the user opens this activity from their devices, there names are added to the recyclerview.

Here's my code:

```
        mDatabase.child(rID).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                    pA = map.get("pName");
                    uA = map.get("pUrl");
                    String cLatS = map.get("cLat").trim();
                    currentLtAU = Double.parseDouble(cLatS);
                    String cLngS = map.get("cLng").trim();
                    currentLnAU = Double.parseDouble(cLngS);

                    layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    prepareData();
                } else {
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                            .make(coordinatorLayout, "Some error occurred. Please retry!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    snackbar.show();
                    onBackPressed();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                Log.d("childRemoved", dataSnapshot.getKey());

                aModelClass = new AModelClass(pA, uA, String.valueOf(currentLtAU), String.valueOf(currentLnAU), null, s, v, availableFrom, rID, userID2, noa);
                aFastItemAdapter.remove(aFastItemAdapter.getAdapterItemCount() - 1);
                aList.setAdapter(aFastItemAdapter);
                aList.smoothScrollToPosition(0);

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Here's `prepareData();` method :-

```
public void prepareData() {
        aModelClass = new AModelClass(pA, uA, String.valueOf(currentLtAU), String.valueOf(currentLnAU), null, s, v, availableFrom, rID, userID2, noa);
        aFastItemAdapter.add(aModelClass);
        aList.setAdapter(aFastItemAdapter);
        aList.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
}
```

The names are getting added but **the problem is** that they aren't getting removed exactly as removed in database. Like in database, `"John"` got removed but here in the list, the last item whatever it is gets removed.

**How can I remove exactly the same name which was removed from the database from the list too?**

Answer (score 1):

you have to refresh adapter after remove data from it.

```
aFastItemAdapter.remove(aFastItemAdapter.getAdapterItemCount() - 1);
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: What `notifyDataSetChanged();` do?

Comment: it will reload your adapter so removed items are remove from view